# PANDAS - PYTHON - LOCALIZAR VALORES DIFERENTES

Tags: python, pandas, join

Boa tarde a todos!
Estou iniciando alguns estudos de Python e para por em pratica estou tentando otimizar algumas rotinas para o meu trabalho.

No setor onde trabalho temos o habito de cruzar muitos dados, principalmente os telefones de clientes, as vezes usamos Excel para fazer um PROCX ou V, mas decidi dar uma otimizada nas rotinas.

No caso estou usando a biblioteca pandas e tenho duas colunas iguais.

DF1 = NUMEROS JA USADOS
DF2 = NUMEROS QUE VOU USAR

Meu objetivo é fazer um cruzamento gerando um terceiro Data frame, onde os números que vou usar cruze com o já usados e retorne apenas os valores que não se repetem.

Esse terceiro DF seria meu arquivo final onde teria apenas oque não teria sido discado.

```
import pandas as pd

###LENDO ARQUIVO NOVO
Novo_Mailing_df = pd.read_csv('Novo_Mailing.csv')

Display('Novo_mailing_df)

0   21900000001
1   21900000002
2   21900000003
3   21900000004
4   21900000005
5   21900000006
6   21900000007
7   21900000008
8   21900000009
9   21900000010
10  21900000011
11  21900000012
12  21900000013
13  21900000014
14  21900000015
15  21900000016
16  21900000017
17  21900000018
18  21900000019
19  21900000020
20  2122771300
21  2122771301
22  2122771302
23  2122771303
24  2122771304
25  2122771305
26  2122771306
27  2122771307
28  2122771308
29  2122771309

###UPANDO JA TRABALHADOS
Discados_Callflex_df = pd.read_csv('Discados_Callflex.csv')

display(Discados_Callflex_df)

0   21900000001
1   21900000002
2   21900000003
3   21900000004
4   21900000005
5   21900000006
6   21900000007
7   21900000008
8   21900000009
9   21900000010
10  21900000011
11  21900000012
12  21900000013
13  21900000014
14  21900000015
15  21900000016
16  21900000017
17  21900000018
18  21900000019
19  21900000020

###USANDO OS JOINS PARA RETORNAR A DIFERENÇA

cruzamento_df = pd.merge(Novo_Mailing_df, Discados_Callflex_df, how='outer', on='telefone', indicator=True)

display(cruzamento_df)

0   21900000001 both
1   21900000002 both
2   21900000003 both
3   21900000004 both
4   21900000005 both
5   21900000006 both
6   21900000007 both
7   21900000008 both
8   21900000009 both
9   21900000010 both
10  21900000011 both
11  21900000012 both
12  21900000013 both
13  21900000014 both
14  21900000015 both
15  21900000016 both
16  21900000017 both
17  21900000018 both
18  21900000019 both
19  21900000020 both
20  2122771300  left_only
21  2122771301  left_only
22  2122771302  left_only
23  2122771303  left_only
24  2122771304  left_only
25  2122771305  left_only
26  2122771306  left_only
27  2122771307  left_only
28  2122771308  left_only
29  2122771309  left_only
```

Foi isso que fiz por hora, mas apenas consigo usar maneiras de devolver oque tem em comum entre um e outro, porem meu objetivo é devolver oque tem tem de diferente entre eles.

Meu objetivo final é saber se no que eu quero trabalhar hoje ja foi trabaçhado em algum outro dia, e no DF novo devolver só oque não trabalhei.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o isin do pandas

Importando o pandas

```
import pandas as pd
```

Criando os dataframes:

```
Novo_Mailing_df = pd.read_csv('../DADOS/Novo_Mailing.csv', sep = ';', names=['Coluna1'])
Discados_Callflex_df = pd.read_csv('../DADOS/Discados_Callflex.csv', sep = ';', names=['Coluna1'])
```

Aqui é a parte onde verificamos se valores de um dataframe estão presentes no outro:

```
Novo_Mailing_df[~Novo_Mailing_df['Coluna1'].isin(Discados_Callflex_df['Coluna1'])]
```

Saída:

|  | Coluna1 |
| --- | --- |
| 20 | 2122771300 |
| 21 | 2122771301 |
| 22 | 2122771302 |
| 23 | 2122771303 |
| 24 | 2122771304 |
| 25 | 2122771305 |
| 26 | 2122771306 |
| 27 | 2122771307 |
| 28 | 2122771308 |
| 29 | 2122771309 |

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno!
Vou tentar aplicar a sua explicação no meu projeto assim que tiver um tempo no  trabalho.
Também irei pesquisar sobre o isin para aprender mais sobre ele.

Comment: Obrigado pela sua ajuda!
Sua solução realmente funcionou , e enquanto pesquisava sobre oque me indicou aprendi algumas outras coisas sobre o PANDAS.

Comment: Fala @DiogenesCosta , tudo bom? que ótimo que pude contribuir e muito bom saber que você aprendeu mais coisas sobre o pandas. Grande abraço!